# Grails app out of sync when using IntelliJ 12.1.2 and Maven projects

Tags: maven, grails, intellij-idea

I have a project that contains amongst other things, a Groovy common code module and a separate Grails web-app module.  I made the change from Eclipse to IntelliJ 12.1.2 and it has been a HUGE improvement.  Everything seems to be working much better - for example, when I add fields to a class in the Groovy project, I instantly see them available in the IntelliSense in the Grails project.  Also, another great benefit is that I was finally able to get debugging of the Grails app working in the IDE (Hooray for not having to litter the code with print statements everywhere!).

The problem that I'm having, however, is that it appears that the code that is run when I do a Run->Run 'Grails:FooProj' or Run->Debug 'Grails:FooProj' is out of sync with the saved code.  For example, I can add a log statement to the code and then try to run it, but it doesn't show up.  It's like it's using a cached version of the jar/wars.

One thing of note is that for my run/debug configs I had to check the "Work offline" box of the Maven Settings so that it would not go out to the nexus to pull down jars.  I want it to use the local changes that I have made to the code and not what was published.

How do I get IntelliJ to use the local code changes that I have made when debugging the web-app?  I can go to the console and do a `mvn clean install` on the common code project and it works fine in IntelliJ after that, but I don't want to drop to the console every time I want to debug my app.

Answer (score 1):

I have a question and a way out for you.

**Question:-**

Do you have the below setting in `BuildConfig` in case you are using Grails version > 2.x? If not can you try adding that and then Run your app.

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    pom true
}
```

**Way Out:-**

In InteliJ, if you go to `Run/Debug Configuration -> Maven Settings -> Before Launch(in bottom)`
and set up a `Before Launch` Configuration of `Run Maven Goal` then every time you run your app, it will implicitly do a `mvn install` for you instead of you doing it in command prompt.

Comment: We are using Grails 2.1.  I added the pom true to the `BuildConfig` but it didn't seem to pick up my changes.  Is there anything else that I need to do?

The "Way Out" method looks somewhat promising, though I'd rather not have to do a mvn install every time as the dependency code doesn't always change.  Also, we have some integration tests that we need to skip, so normally we do a `mvn clean install -D skipITs`, but I don't see how I can pass that param in the "Way Out".

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE

An alternative could be :

- Removing your Maven dependency in the Grails pom.xml
- Ensuring that the jar of the common project ends up in grails-project-dir/lib
- Adding an IDE classpath dependency on the project-dir/lib/common.jar file

---

The common code is a maven dependency, it is picked up from your local Maven cache. You can run maven clean install from the IDE too...

If you don't want that create a simple non-maven project and add the common project as dependency, then your changes will be picked up on the fly.

Hope it is clear enough

Comment: If common code is a maven dependency, wouldn't I want the web-app to also be a maven project?  I have the common code as a dependency, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: My answer is related to whether or not you want your changes to be picked up automatically (if having to run maven install from the IDE or the command line is a problem for you). 

Convert your Maven projects to simple java projects for development purposes(Project dependency on the common code), if you want auto-refresh.
If you're using Maven it means that you want your dependencies to be picked up from your local Maven cache...

Comment: I don't mind the dependency being picked up from the local Maven cache (it's actually what I'd prefer).  I'm guessing it's my lack of understanding how IntelliJ installs the jars to the local MVN repo.  Is there something specific that I need to do to publish it to the local repo? I'm guessing that doing a Build->Make 'Foo' isn't publishing to the local mvn repo.  How do I do that?  Is there a way in the Grails project to tell if the common code is out of date and needs to be compiled and pushed to the local repo?

Comment: I think I found a big step.  So under the Maven Projects tab I can change the install target to run after doing a make.  Now I just need to figure out how to make it conditional so it doesn't do the whole install process if nothing has changed.